# Istanbul cover tests hang, then abort after 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I'm using Istanbul for code coverage for a web app I'm creating. Whenever I run `npm run cover --color=always` (which runs :  `../node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js -- node_modules/.bin/babel-    istanbul cover test/index.js --report=cobertura --print=detail --x=dist/**` )

but nothing appears on the terminal until around 60 seconds later, when I get 
this error:

```
TAP version 13
# application server
Aborted (core dumped)
```

However, if I write something that causes an error (like an undefined function) at the bottom of the index.js file, it will print the coverage out, along with that error.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I have just run into this exact issue when running tests using the same tooling. What I discovered is that it is caused by a missing package or a package of the wrong version.

Just `rm -rf node_modules` and doing a fresh `npm install` seems to ensure that it is fixed.

Hope this helps you or anyone who comes across this in the future!